# Magento - how to hook into order reorder

Tags: magento

When a customer reorders I need to include a reference to the original order ID on the new order. I can see how to add an attribute for this in `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_quote` (I think!), but I can't see how to hook into the reorder.

The reorder is quite simple and is done in `app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Controller\Abstract.php->reorderAction`. It simply copies order items to the cart and then opens the cart. But how can I hook into this to add an orderId crossreference?

I can probably just copy this to local and edit it (correct?) but that's not a smart way of doing it because I've then taken everything done in Abstract.php and made a local copy of it.

I guess I could also create a custom module that does the reorder and point the "reorder" link to my custom module. But again, that's a bit hacky and I'd prefer to hook into the process if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can hook into the `controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_reorder` event and then get the order id parameter on the observer

```
$oldOrderId=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
```

Create a new column for the quote and order table on a sql installer

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
$options = array(
'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
);
$installer->addAttribute('quote', 'old_order_id', $options);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'old_order_id', $options);
$installer->endSetup();
```

then save the parameter order_id to the quote object on the observer

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setOldOrderId($oldOrderId)->save();
```

and create a fieldset on your config.xml to transfer the value of that attribute to the order object

```
<global>
     <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote>
            <old_order_id>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </old_order_id>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

There might be some experimentation involved, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks @changeling. From a more general perspective, how have you determined that there is a controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_reorder event to hook into and extactly how does one hook into it? I've created my module and observer, but what's the correct event to put in config.xml?

Comment: Some refer to events in a different way. For example sales_order_place_after to hook in after an order is placed. So would this be sales_order_reorder_before?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think can work. As far as I can tell, there is no event dispatched before or after 'sales_order_reorder'. Seems Magento provides only a limited set of events and reordering is not one of them! Would be better if Magento had a mechanism for firing a before & after event for **every** action instead of hardcoding a limited set of events.

Comment: this type of event is one that is fired in every action predispatch on every controller, they are not explicitly declared

Comment: it will work because when the controller method 'reorder' is called the event is fired, you then get the order_id and add it to the current quote in the observer, the action will then add the previous items to the cart and the old_order_id reference will be preserved.

Comment: Ok, I've done it a different way now (sorry, seems there's no notification of comments posted in SO!). For completeness of the answer, can you explain exactly what you mean by "_hook into the controller_action_predispatch_sales_order_reorder event_" with a simple example of how to do it?